# Change the styling of a child div with CSS hover on parent JSX

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui, jsx

I'm using the material-ui table. Within it I am mapping the rows as such:

```
.map(row => (
  <TableRow
    className={classes.clickableRow}
    key={row[rowKey]}
  >
    {generateTableCheckbox(row)}
    {
      columns.map(column => (
        <TableCell
          onClick={onRowClick && !row.disabled
            ? event => onRowClick(event, row)
            : null}
          key={column.field}
          className={classes.body}
          title={column.alt ? column.alt(row) : row[column.field]}
        >
          {column.format ? column.format(row) : row[column.field]}
        </TableCell>
      ))
    }
    {generateTableHoverOptions(row)}
  </TableRow>
))
```

As you can see the `className` gets set to `clickableRow`.

The `TableRow` contains a hover options div that is rendered & placed to the right with this function:

```
const generateTableHoverOptions = () => {
  if (selected) {
    return (
      <TableCell className={classes.rightHoverIcon}>
        <Icon>expand_more</Icon>
      </TableCell>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

I want to be able to change the `backgroundColor` of the `<TableCell />` (className being `rightHoverIcon`) that is returned from that function, when hovering over the `clickableRow`. Here is the js CSS I've been attempting to use:

```
clickableRow: {
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  '&:hover > .rightHoverIcon': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
},
rightHoverIcon: {
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  marginTop: 1,
  height: 49,
  position: 'absolute',
  right: 0,
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  borderBottomColor: 'rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)',
},
```

The code expecting to target the div is `'&:hover > .rightHoverIcon'`, I've tried other variations such as `'&:hover ~ .rightHoverIcon'` and `&:hover .rightHoverIcon` but none seem to be working.

I've checked other questions on SO and while similar they're not like my issue. If anyone has any ideas please let me know!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you styling with js - why not just use css?

Comment: We're exporting our components with `withStyles` from `import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&:hover > .rightHoverIcon` expects `.rightHoverIcon` to be a *direct child* of `clickableRow`, but it isn't (there's a table cell in-between). Remove the `>` so you're using a [*descendant combinator*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators) instead of a [*child combinator*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#child-combinators):

```
clickableRow: {
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  '&:hover .rightHoverIcon': {
  // -----^
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
},
```

Or, alternately, if you want to use child combinators, you'll need at least two of them (assuming `TableCell` only puts one element between its parent and the icon), e.g. `&:hover > something-for-the-cell > .rightHoverIcon`.

Comment: Can you help me to show Icon only if parent element is hovered. If no hover on the parent Child should be invisible. With this example is helpful.